# How to pass params to jsp page from Restful method in java

Tags: java, jsp, rest, websphere, websphere-7

Searched in SOF but couldn't find similar which need params passed.

I have a Restful webservice in java in WAS 7 which takes few params from URL. how do I pass this to a jsp.
This class is not a servlet.
When I do as below:

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest hsRequest;  

@Path("myRestPath)
public void myRestMethod(@QueryParam("user") String userName)
{
  hsRequest.setAttribute("username",userName);  
  hsRequest.getRequestDispatcher("myRestJsp.jsp").forward(hsRequest,hsResponse);
}
```

I get this error:

```
500: RuntimeException:RequestWrapper objects must extend ServletRequestWrapper or HttpServletRequestWrapper
```

What is my error or is there a better way to pass params to jsp?

Comment: What jax-rs provider are you using, built in (with feature pack) or custom? I have this working on WAS 8.5.5 (which uses wink). Don't have v7 at hand to try unfortunately.

Comment: @Gas I use the one that comes with Websphere 7. Is there any other way to call jsp from my java methods?

Answer (score 0):

something like this fixed it........

```
return new Viewable("myPage.jsp",null);
```

where Viewable is from com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable;
Thanks anyways.